# "Add" with "2" argument(s)" PowerCLI error when trying to use a hash table

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am retrieving a JSON file that I am placing in a hashing table.
When a certain value matches
I want to make sure that this is matched:

```
"tier0_path": "/global-infra/tier-0s/89bde5c0-83d1-4f76-af90-1fa88b1ab462",
```

So the tier "tier0_path" needs to be exactly the value. If this is the case I should get a SUCCESS message if not I should get a NOT SUCCESS message.

My script is kind of working, but I am getting the following error:

```
========================================
/global-infra/tier-0s/89bde5c0-83d1-4f76-af90-1fa88b1ab462
========================================
t1-stretched is connected to t0-gateway-stretched
t1-stretched is connected to t0-gateway-stretched
MethodInvocationException: C:\hol\podStatusCheck\Lab-9.8.ps1:54
Line |
  54 |              [void]$testingHash.Add('T1G',$t1g)
     |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'T1G'  Key being added: 'T1G'"
MethodInvocationException: C:\my\podStatusCheck\Lab-9.8.ps1:55
Line |
  55 |              [void]$testingHash.Add('IST1G',$true)
     |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'IST1G'  Key being added: 'IST1G'"
OH NO!
```

This is my code:

```
#I have left out the previous code where I retrieve the ID of the T0 Gateway.
#
#Verify if the T0 path is retrieved correctly
    Write-Host "========================================"
    Write-Host $t1t0connection
    Write-Host "========================================"

    #Get Tier 1 Gateways    
    $resultsT1g = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$uri/global-manager/api/v1/global-infra/tier-1s" -Headers $header

    #Parse return and create an object from the results
    $t1gItems = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $resultsT1g.Content -Depth 10 -AsHashtable

    #Find the Tier 1 Gateway and store it in the testing hashtable
    foreach ($t1g in $t1gItems.results)
    {
        #If ($t1gItems.results){continue}
        If ($t1g.tier0_path -eq $t1t0connection)
        {
            Write-Output "t1-stretched is connected to t0-gateway-stretched"
            [void]$testingHash.Add('T1G',$t1g)
            [void]$testingHash.Add('IST1G',$true)
        }
    }

    If ($null -eq $testingHash.T1G)
    {
        [void]$testingHash.Add('IST1G',$false)
        Write-Error "t1-stretched is not connected to t0-gateway-stretched"
    }

    #Output pass/fail
    If (($testingHash.T1G -eq $true))
    {
        Write-Output "YES!!!"
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "OH NO!"
    }
    }
}
```

These are the results of the API call (in Postman):

```
{
    "tier0_path": "/global-infra/tier-0s/89bde5c0-83d1-4f76-af90-1fa88b1ab462",
    "failover_mode": "NON_PREEMPTIVE",
    "enable_standby_relocation": false,
    "route_advertisement_types": [
        "TIER1_CONNECTED",
        "TIER1_IPSEC_LOCAL_ENDPOINT"
    ],
    "force_whitelisting": false,
    "default_rule_logging": false,
    "disable_firewall": false,
    "ipv6_profile_paths": [
        "/global-infra/ipv6-ndra-profiles/default",
        "/global-infra/ipv6-dad-profiles/default"
    ],
    "federation_config": {
        "transit_segment_id": "35f39031-7668-45b5-b838-1dc8ef173201",
        "global_overlay_id": 195833
    },
    "pool_allocation": "ROUTING",
    "intersite_config": {
        "last_admin_active_epoch": 1684291104,
        "intersite_transit_subnet": "169.254.32.0/20",
        "primary_site_path": "/global-infra/sites/lm-site-a"
    },
    "ha_mode": "ACTIVE_STANDBY",
    "advanced_config": {
        "traffic_back_to_source": false,
        "centralized_mode_enabled": false
    },
    "resource_type": "Tier1",
    "id": "t1-stretched",
    "display_name": "t1-stretched",
    "path": "/global-infra/tier-1s/t1-stretched",
    "relative_path": "t1-stretched",
    "parent_path": "/global-infra",
    "remote_path": "",
    "unique_id": "2d73d4cb-0c41-4c7c-ba30-8259bb80a352",
    "owner_id": "11458d41-235c-4efe-816e-84513ffc4d3b",
    "origin_site_id": "11458d41-235c-4efe-816e-84513ffc4d3b",
    "marked_for_delete": false,
    "overridden": false,
    "_create_time": 1684290540239,
    "_create_user": "admin",
    "_last_modified_time": 1684291104842,
    "_last_modified_user": "admin",
    "_system_owned": false,
    "_protection": "NOT_PROTECTED",
    "_revision": 1
}
```

These are the failing lines:

```
            [void]$testingHash.Add('T1G',$t1g)
            [void]$testingHash.Add('IST1G',$true)
```

I did a Google search, and I have either the same keys that I am trying to store, or the value of a key is empty, I have tried several fixes, but none of them worked ...

Can someone help me with this, please?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Busy trying to fix this the whole evening now...

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're trying to achieve, but if the intent is to _update potentially preexisting_ entries, use something like `$testingHash['T1G'] = ...`

Comment: This is not working:

            `[void]$testingHash['T1G'].Add('T1G',$t1g)`
            `[void]$testingHash['IST1G'].Add('IST1G',$true)`

Comment: The index notation must be used _in lieu of_ an `.Add()` call. E.g., `$testingHash['T1G'] = $t1g`

Comment: There’s something inconsistent between your example json and the way you’re calling ```foreach ($t1g in $t1gItems.results)``` - according to your postman response, ```$t1gItems``` doesn’t have a ```results``` property, the same as your other question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76400604/hashtable-output-is-not-matching-my-variable-in-powershell-script#comment134721332_76400604. While it’s probably unrelated to your error, it’s distracting to try to reproduce the issue locally if the code sample doesn’t match the data sample…

Comment: @mclayton you are right ... I used the wrong URI and therefore the property was also not correct. I forgot to add the `t1-stretched` at the end of my URI. Thank you once again! I will post the final code now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a mistake in my URI (thanks @mclayton for pointing this out) my URI was:

```
"$uri/global-manager/api/v1/global-infra/tier-1s"
```

But needed to be:

```
"$uri/global-manager/api/v1/global-infra/tier-1s/t1-stretched"
```

And I also needed to change the property lookup from:

```
    foreach ($t1g in $t1gItems.results)
```

To:

```
    foreach ($t1g in $t1gItems)
```

The final code is now like this:

```
    #Get Tier 1 Gateways    
    $resultsT1g = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$uri/global-manager/api/v1/global-infra/tier-1s/t1-stretched" -Headers $header

    #Parse return and create an object from the results
    $t1gItems = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $resultsT1g.Content -Depth 10 -AsHashtable

    #Find the Tier 1 Gateway and store it in the testing hashtable
    foreach ($t1g in $t1gItems)
    {
        #If ($t1gItems.results){continue}
        If ($t1g.tier0_path -eq $t1t0connection)
        {
            Write-Output "t1-stretched is connected to t0-gateway-stretched"
            [void]$testingHash.Add('T1G',$t1g)
            [void]$testingHash.Add('IST1G',$true)   
        }
    }

    If ($null -eq $testingHash.T1G)
    {
        [void]$testingHash.Add('IST1G',$false)
        Write-Error "t1-stretched is not connected to t0-gateway-stretched"
    }

    #Output pass/fail
    If (($testingHash.IST1G -eq $true))
    {
        Write-Output "YES!!!"
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "OH NO!"
    }
    }
}
```